# Prove that the equation $x + \cos(x) + e^{x} = 0$ has *exactly* one root

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, derivatives

> **Question :** Prove that the equation $x + \cos(x) + e^{x} = 0$ has
>   *exactly* one root

---

*This is what I thought of doing:*

$$\text{Let} \ \ \  f(x) = x + \cos(x) + e^{x}$$
By using the Intermediate Value Theorem on the open interval $(-\infty, \infty)$, and then by showing that

$$\left(\lim_{x \to -\infty}f(x) < 0 < \lim_{x \to +\infty}f(x)\right) \lor \left(\lim_{x \to +\infty}f(x) < 0 < \lim_{x \to -\infty}f(x)\right)$$

I could show that $\exists\  x \in \mathbb{R} \ s.t.\  f(x) = 0$.

However this method, although it does show the existence of an $x$ such that $f(x)=0$, it doesn't show that there is ***only* one $x$**  that satisfies the statement $f(x)=0$.

---

The original question, suggest's using either *Rolle's Theorem* or the *Mean Value Theorem*, however we face the same problem with both theorems as both theorems prove the existence of ***at least* a single $x$** (or any arbitrary number) satisfying their given statements, they don't prove the existence of ***only one $x$*** satisfying their statements.

All three theorem's I've mentioned here :

1. *Intermediate Value Theorem*
2. *Rolle's Theorem*
3. *Mean Value Theorem*

Can all be used to show that the equation $x + cos(x) + e^{x} = 0$ has ***at least*** one root, but they can't be used to show $x + cos(x) + e^{x} = 0$ has ***only*** one root. (Or can they?)

How can this problem be solved then, using either Rolle's Theorem or the Mean Value Theorem (or even the Intermediate Value Theorem)

Comment: Question: Does an equaltion have roots or solutions? I've always thought it was the latter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:
Consider the derivative:
$$
1-\sin(x)+e^x.
$$
Since $1\geq \sin(x)$, $1-\sin(x)\geq0$.  Therefore, the derivative is always positive.  If there were two roots, then there would be a place where the derivative is zero.  (why?)

Comment: Is there a solution working without derivatives (?)

Comment: @Imago Unlikely.

Comment: How do you see that it is unlikely? I find it easily believeable that there is a root between $\frac{-\pi}{2} $ and $0$ and beyond  $\frac{-\pi}{2} $  unlikely to be another one. But I think argumentation would go in a similar direction as using derivatives... mhm..

Comment: @Imago I have added an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=x+\sin x + e^x$, then $f'(x)=1-\cos x+ e^x>0$ implies that $f(x)$ is monotonicaly increasing so $f(x)=0$ has almost one real root. Since $f(-\infty)=-\infty$  and $f(\infty)=+\infty$, so by IVT this eq. has one real root. Hence the eq. Has exactly one real root.

Answer (score 1):

The Intermediate Value Theorem give you existence of one $x$ satisfying their statements, for the unicity you have to show the bijection of $f(x)=1+\cos x+ e^x$
Consider this fonction $$f(x)=x+\cos x+e^x$$
For all $ x\in \mathbb{R}, f'(x)=1-\sin(x) + e^{x}$ and $|sinx|\le 1$ then  $1-\sin x\ge0\Longrightarrow f'(x)\ge0$.
So, $\displaystyle{\lim _{x\to +\infty} f(x)=\lim _{x\to +\infty}x\left(\dfrac{1}{x}+\dfrac{\cos x}{x}+\dfrac{e^x}{x}\right)=+\infty}$ and $\displaystyle{\lim _{x\to -\infty} f(x)=\lim _{x\to -\infty}x\left(\dfrac{1}{x}+\dfrac{\cos x}{x}+\dfrac{e^x}{x}\right)=-\infty}$
Finally $f$ increasing and $f(\mathbb{R})=\mathbb{R}$, hence they are only one root for $f(x)=0$ i.e $1+\cos x +e^x=0.$

Answer (score 0):

Consider the first derivate of it:
$f'(x)=1-\sin(x) + e^{x} \ge e^{x}$, for $x \in R$.
So function is grow up , now you should use the Rolle's theorem

Comment: @MichaelBurr yes

Answer (score -1):

The given equation can be written as $$x+\cos x=-e^x$$

$x+\cos x$ is a familiar increasing [graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator).

$-e^x$ is also easy to draw.

They intersect just once.

Comment: You have not justified your answer at all.  How do you know that $x \mapsto x+\cos(x)$ is increasing (hint:  use the derivative)?  What feature of the "easy to draw" $x \mapsto -\mathrm{e}^x$ is important?  How do you *know* that there is only one point of intersection?  Graphs can be a good place to start for building intuition or heuristics, but they don't provide *proof*.